# How to disable double greater than symbol view at tab spaces in Kate?

Tags: kate

A few months back I enabled this view. Now I dont want to see that ">>" anymore. I don't remember from which menu item I enabled this ">>" view. Please help me to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I hope this will be helpfull to someone in the future.

Settings --> Configure-Kate --> Editor Component -->Appearance --> (Under General tab) Whitespace Highlighting --> Highlight  tabulators (uncheck the box).

/*
Right bottom, I found the same option as "Tab size", in that "Indentation Mode", but its not working. May be I might be wrong about this.
*/